# Как получить список нужных записей из таблицы ManyToMany

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

у меня есть человек, который может участвовать в множестве проектах с разной ролью в каждом.

Вопрос : Как правильно написать контроллер, чтобы при переходе на страницу человека нужно получать информацию, в каких проектах он участвует вместе ролью.

Использую : spring boot , thymeleaf, jpa , postgre.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать ? или исправить структуру для правильной реализации.
Большое спасибо !
  [image: c[схема]
Проект

```
     @Entity

      public class Project {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long idProject;

      private String nameProject;

      @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "project",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    List<ProjectUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ProjectUser> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<ProjectUser> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    // getter, setter , equals , hashcode
```

Человек

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Usr")
    public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long idUser;

    private String name;

    // фамилия
    private String surname;

    // отчество
    private String patronymic;
         @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
    List<ProjectUser> projects = new ArrayList<>();
    // getter, setter, hashcode,equals
```

ProjectUserId

```
        @Embeddable
        public class ProjectUserId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "id_project")
        private Long idProject;

        @Column(name = "id_user")
        private Long idUser;

        public ProjectUserId() {
        }

        public ProjectUserId(Long idProject, Long idUser) {
            this.idProject = idProject;
            this.idUser = idUser;
        }

        public Long getIdProject() {
            return idProject;
        }

        public Long getIdUser() {
            return idUser;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            ProjectUserId that = (ProjectUserId) o;
            return Objects.equals(idProject, that.idProject) &&
                    Objects.equals(idUser, that.idUser);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(idProject, idUser);
        }
    }
```

ProjectUser

```
        @Entity(name = "ProjectUser")
        @Table(name = "project_user")

        public class ProjectUser {

        @EmbeddedId
        private ProjectUserId id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @MapsId("id_project")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_project")
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @MapsId("id_user")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
        private User user;

        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        @Column(name = "created_on")
        private Date createdOn = new Date();

        // статус человека
        @Column(name = "RoleUser")
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private RoleUser roleUser;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            ProjectUser that = (ProjectUser) o;
            return Objects.equals(project, that.project) &&
                    Objects.equals(user, that.user);
       // getter, setter
        }
```

controller

```
  @GetMapping("/oneUser/{id}")
    public String listOne(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
       ....
        return "operations/oneUser";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по структуре Ваших таблиц, Вы хотите в смежной таблице user_project еще указывать и роль пользователя. С точки зрения архитектуры построения БД, думаю это не совсем правильное решение. В текущей архитектуре для получения того, что Вы ищете в DAO-слое нужно написать что-то подобное:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM project_user u WHERE u.User.id_user = :id")
List<ProjectUser> getProjectsByUser(long id);
```

Этот запрос выдаст Вам все записи по нужному пользователю и, соответственно, со всеми проектами и ролями в них. Далее уже из полученного списка можете достать названия проектов и ролей в них

Comment: Добрый вечер, запрос помог. Большое спасибо ! Вы написали что с точки зрения архитектуры это не совсем верно решение, вы можете подсказать, как было бы правильнее реализовать ?

Comment: обычно практика следующая: сводные таблицы manyToMany состоят только из айди сущностей, которые они объединяют; в БД не принято дублировать записи (в Вашем случае роли в проектах для пользователей будут дублироваться, я бы вынес список ролей в другую таблицу и объеденил ее с таблицей пользователей в связь manyToMany или другую): дату создания я бы вынес в таблицу проектов, так как она к ним на прямую относиться.